# Using certain javascript code on mobile devices only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a way that only allows this particular javascript code to run on screen sizes that are less than 900 pixels. This code is used to set up a simple left and right navigation button on mobile devices. However, when I try and use matchMedia it totally messes up my code but does not throw any errors. How would you approach this issues?

```
   var flavorScroll = (function() {

        let widthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 901px)");


    if (widthMatch.matches) {
        var flavorBox1 = document.body.querySelector('#flavor-box-1');
        var flavorBox2 = document.body.querySelector('#flavor-box-2');
        var flavorBox3 = document.body.querySelector('#flavor-box-3');
        var flavorBox4 = document.body.querySelector('#flavor-box-4');

        var buttonRight = document.body.querySelector('#flavorButtonRight');
        var buttonLeft = document.body.querySelector('#flavorButtonLeft');

        var step = 1;

        leftButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        function flavorDisplayer(currentStep){
            if(currentStep === 1) {
                flavorBox1.style.display = 'block';

                flavorBox2.style.display = 'none';

                leftButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if(currentStep === 2) {
                flavorBox2.style.display = 'block';

                flavorBox1.style.display = 'none';
                flavorBox3.style.display = 'none';

                leftButton.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
            } else if(currentStep === 3) {
                flavorBox3.style.display = 'block';

                flavorBox2.style.display = 'none';
                flavorBox4.style.display = 'none';

                rightButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
            } else if(currentStep === 4) {
                flavorBox4.style.display = 'block';

                flavorBox3.style.display = 'none';

                rightButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }





        buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
            step += 1;

            flavorDisplayer(step);
        });

        buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
            step -= 1;

            flavorDisplayer(step);
        });

    } else {

        }

})();
```

Comment: Show your matchMedia attempt. Remember the objective here is to help fix code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Ok I edited my question

Comment: One issue I see is you aren't accounting for resize on larger devices scenario. Where do you call flavorScroll () ?

Comment: Also functions should never be declared in a conditional

Comment: What should be included in the conditional statement then? I guess I don't understand what should be included in the if statement for widthMatch

Comment: What specifically gets messed up? Layout or functionality? If you're calling `flavorScroll()` on window resize, you might be binding many more event listeners than you intend, which could cause problems.

Comment: When I try to use any kind of matchMedia code the left button visibility is set to visible and neither the left or right button works meaning the next list of flavors will no display. It is just stuck on flavor box one. This code works fine without matchMedia but then the issue becomes they display one at a time on larger screens when I want them all displaying on larger screens

Comment: Really need to start from where does this get called..only on page load or in another event handler? Would realy help to provide a basic [mcve]

Comment: It is an IIFE and I call it at the very end of the code block I uploaded. It is called on page load

Comment: If you added another argument to `flavorDisplayer()` for direction, could put the matchmedia inside it as well as the step increment/decrement and don't change step or change the styles if too narrow. That also starts fixing issue to do with resize on larger screens. The  event listeners will always  be there...it's just a matter what happens when they are triggered

Answer (score 0):

This is a handy util I use...

```
var breakpoint = {
  is(s) {
    const size = s.trim()
    const sizes = {
      xsmall: "480px",
      small: "576px",
      medium: "780px",
      large: "992px",
      xlarge: "1200px",
    }

    if (sizes.hasOwnProperty(size)) {
      // return mq(`only screen and (min-width: ${sizes[size]})`)
      return window.matchMedia(`only screen and (min-width: ${sizes[size]})`).matches
    }

    throw new ReferenceError(`The size ${size} is not a valid breakpoint: ${JSON.stringify(sizes)}`)
  },
}
```

Then you can wrap your function in an if statement i.e.

```
if (breakpoint.is("medium")) {
...
}
```

Comment: This is quite beautiful. But the OP says they tried `matchMedia` without success and I wonder what that specific problem is.

Comment: Gave it a shot but the same issue persists. Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

Use screen.width to get the current size of the screen the user is working on. Then use that value to limit when the code is executed.

```
    var scrn = screen.width
    if (scrn < 2000) { console.log(1); };
```